Can rigged Hilbert spaces formalize $\langle x | y \rangle = \delta(x - y)$?
I'm familiar with QM and some spectral theory, so I understand the intuition behind $\langle x | y \rangle = \delta(x - y)$. I also know that rigged Hilbert spaces (RHSs) allow one to make some of Dirac notation rigorous. I have been reading up on RHSs, but I still don't see if/how it can interpret $\langle x | y \rangle$ (and any similar bra-ket expression in which both arguments are distributions—see below for details).
In the RHS framework, one has a Gelfand triple $\Phi\subseteq\mathcal H\subseteq \Phi^\times$, and "position eigenstates" $|x\rangle$, which are intuitively Dirac delta functions, are interpreted as distributions in $\Phi^\times$. Then statements like $\langle \psi|x\rangle = \psi^*(x)$ are interpreted as saying that the distribution $|x\rangle \in \Phi^\times$ acting on the state $\langle \psi | \in \Phi$ is equal to $\psi^*(x)$. But in order to make sense of $\langle x | y \rangle = \delta(x - y)$, we need to have distributions in both arguments of $\langle\cdot|\cdot\rangle$ [and it would appear the bra-ket is then $\Phi^\times$-valued]. A similar issue arises if we try to make sense of $\langle p|p'\rangle = 2\pi\delta(p - p')$ or $\langle x|p\rangle = \frac1{2\pi}e^{ipx}$. These expressions are important on an intuitive level, so I would think one of the goals of RHS would be to make them rigorous—but the resource I have been looking at* doesn't define $\langle\cdot|\cdot\rangle$ with distributions in both arguments (as far as I can tell).

*M. Gadella and F. Gómez, On the Mathematical Basis of the Dirac Formulation of Quantum Mechanics.

Usually I see $\langle x|\psi\rangle=\psi(x)$

@BioPhysicist Thanks, I updated the post.

This book is very clear and rigorous, you may enjoy it: Franco Gallone, Hilbert Space and Quantum Mechanics

There is no chance to rigorously embody that identity in the rigged Hilbert space (Gelfand Vilenkin) formalism. That is because, in the said approach, only elements of  $\Phi^\times$ acts on elements of $\Phi$ and $\delta$ belongs only to the former. Same result for the momentum case.
It is possible to further force the formalism to define the action of a distribution on another one when some requirements (on micro local wavefront sets) are satisfied. But this would make an already very cumbersome formalism even more heavy to handle.
Personally I dislike the rigged Hilbert space rigorous formulation: it is very cumbersome and ineffective. It is much better to use it a the heuristic level and next to rigorously prove the achieved result by means of more standard procedures. (I never faced a case where this double procedure does not work.)

Could you recommend any resources that discuss the distribution-acting-on-distribution formalism that you mentioned in the second paragraph? I can understand your distaste for the RHS formulation. My interest is mainly out of theoretical curiosity, motivated by the following tension.

In finite dimensional spaces like $\mathbb C^n$, we can think of the Fourier transform in two different ways: (1) A unitary matrix acting on the components of a vector, or (2) a change of basis from a “position” basis $|n\rangle$ to a “Fourier” basis $|k\rangle$. When going to $L^2(\mathbb R)$, in the standard approach only the first version remains rigorous, since $\mathcal F$ is a unitary map on $L^2$. I think it would be conceptually appealing if there was a rigorous way to still view the Fourier transform as an honest change of “basis” in the infinite dimensional case.

Even if the details are cumbersome and it is not needed in practice, I would be interested to see how it could be done.

I. M. Gelfand and N. Ya. Vilenkin. Generalized Functions, vol. 4: Some Applications of Harmonic Analysis. Rigged Hilbert Spaces. Academic Press, New York, 1964. and
K. Maurin, Generalized Eigenfunction Expansions and Unitary Representations of Topological Groups, Polish Scientific Publishers, Warsaw, 1968. These are references on rigirous bra ket formalism

Regarding advanced manipulation of distributions, an introduction can be found in the  first volume of Hoermander textbooks on distributions, where he introduces the  wavefront set formalism
